# select django orm columns dynamically

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a report table with 10 fields/columns. I want to allow the user to dynamically select which columns he wants in the report. Can this be done in Django ORM

Example

If user wants column1 and column2 then it should be like this

```
obj = ReportTable.objects.values('column1', 'column2')
```

If user wants column5, column6, column9, column10 then it should be like this

```
obj = ReportTable.objects.values('column5', 'column6', 'column9', 'column10')
```

Is this doable in django orm or should I use cursor or raw queries

Comment: Your method above should work fine, just get the list of columns from the user somehow. You can also just use ReportTable.objects.all() and then use getattr to get the required values.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of using `only` and `values`. your example will work fine:

```
ReportTable.objects.values('column5', 'column6', 'column9', 'column10')
```

Alternatively:

```
ReportTable.objects.only('column5', 'column6', 'column9', 'column10')
```

I suggest using `objects.only` if you are looking for something equivalent to `SELECT column5, column6, column9, column10 FROM`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The thing is the choosing of columns is dynamic. So he may choose any combination and I cannot have that many 'if' statements. If you see the answer I have posted, it takes a list of values which is formed from user input.

Comment: @PrabhakarShanmugam it takes string, so there's lots of ways to pass user selection from front to back. Glad you found your preferred method though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this question. Django orm values takes positional arguments.

```
args = ['column5', 'column6', 'column9', 'column10']
obj = ReportTable.objects.values(*tuple(args))
```

Now the args can be got from the user, using regular get or post method.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass variables in queryset instead of hardcoded string. and for user choices a form can be filled by user.

```
choices = request.POST.getlist('choices')
obj = ReportTable.objects.values(*choices)
```

obj will be your expected output

and in template multiple input field can be use with same name.

```html
<input name="choices">
<input name="choices">
<input name="choices">
```